# CSS Sprites still making new requests

Tags: css, performance, css-sprites

I am using CSS sprites however when i hover over it is making another request for the same image and causing a flicker. Any idea why its making 2 requests? Here is my code:

```
.btn-red-lrg .left {background:url(../images/site-sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 0px transparent;width: 9px;}     
.btn-red-lrg:hover .left {background:url(../images/site-sprite.png) no-repeat 0px -37px transparent;width: 9px;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dont' use  the [`background`-shorthand](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background) property. Use [`background-position`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-position) instead, since you only want to update the position.

```
/* no need for width, background-image etc. */
.btn-red-lrg:hover .left {background-position: 0px -37px;}
```

Specifying a `background-image:url(...)` on the `:hover` pseudo-class can result in a new request if the caching mechanism aren't sufficient or the expiration date is missing/wrong (see [Jeff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9367685/1139697)). Altering the position only won't result in a new request regardless of the browser.

Comment: While this is a good practice, how does this address the question?

Comment: @Jeff: Specifying a `background-image:url(...)` on the `:hover` pseudo-class can result in a new request by the browser if the caching mechanism aren't sufficient or (as you stated in your answer) the expiration date is missing or wrong. Altering the position only won't result in a new request regardless of the browser. But you're right, I didn't answer the question *"Any idea why its making 2 requests?"*, my bad :/. +1 on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

What browser are you using? This is a known bug in using Internet Explorer 6. The solution is to add expires headers to the image on the server.

- [Content Expiration in IIS 6](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=truehttp://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx?mfr=true)
- [Content Expiration in IIS 7](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770661%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)
- [Content expiration in Apache 2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html)

Comment: All browsers. Chrome, IE8, Firefox